Catholicism: Is Sunday Observance Necessary for Salvation?
For Catholics, is Sunday observance necessary for salvation?
Is Sunday observed in the same way as the Sabbath was observed, or is there a difference?
Additionally, what about the observance of the day and the Eucharist? Is it mandatory to attend Mass and receive the Eucharist?
If possible, I would like to know about Catholic documents or catechisms that define this. Thank you!

Canon Law binds Catholics to attend Mass on Sundays under pain of mortal sin. It also requires Catholics to abstain from any works which hinder worship, joy, or suitable relaxation.

Can. 1247 On Sundays and other holy days of obligation, the faithful are obliged to participate in the Mass.
Moreover, they are to abstain from those works and aVairs which hinder the worship to be rendered to God, the joy proper to the Lord’s day, or the suitable relaxation of mind and body.
Can. 1248 §1. A person who assists at a Mass celebrated anywhere in a Catholic rite either on the feast day itself or in the evening of the preceding day satisfies the obligation of participating in the Mass.
§2. If participation in the eucharistic celebration becomes impossible because of the absence of a sacred minister or for another grave cause, it is strongly recommended that the faithful take part in a liturgy of the word if such a liturgy is celebrated in a parish church or other sacred place according to the prescripts of the diocesan bishop or that they devote themselves to prayer for a suitable time alone, as a family, or, as the occasion permits, in groups of families.

As to whether this observance is necessary for salvation, in a strict sense it isn't, since someone could be baptized on his death bed and be saved, though he never observed this canon. Likewise, someone could confess on his death bed that he never or rarely observed this canon, and could be saved in that way. These are ordinary means of salvation. Extraordinary means could be available in any situation whatsoever, and we cannot know if they are or not. But someone could be saved through ordinary means of salvation without observing this canon, if they repented of having sinned by not observing this canon.
One for whom it is impossible to observe this canon (perhaps he is too ill to attend Mass, or he must do some necessary work, such as firefighting, because of the urgency with which that work must be accomplished) does not even sin if he does not observe it in that case.
Reception of the Eucharist is required at minimum once per year, according to the precepts of the Church. A Catholic is under no obligation to receive the Eucharist at every Sunday Mass.
